# postgres not using postgres.conf file?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-18.04, postgresql-10

I have a postgres setup on my ubuntu 18.04 server.
I have changed the `listen_addresses` property to `'*'` but it doesn't seem like the postgres server is following this.

currently the first part of the file:

```
# - Connection Settings -

listen_addresses = '*'      # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                # comma-separated list of addresses;
                # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                # (change requires restart)
port = 5432             # (change requires restart)
max_connections = 100           # (change requires restart)
#superuser_reserved_connections = 3 # (change requires restart)
unix_socket_directories = '/var/run/postgresql' # comma-separated list of directories
                # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_group = ''         # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_permissions = 0777     # begin with 0 to use octal notation
                # (change requires restart)
#bonjour = off              # advertise server via Bonjour
                # (change requires restart)
#bonjour_name = ''          # defaults to the computer name
                # (change requires restart)
```

As a test, I changed the `port` setting to a different port and restarted the postgres server and psql stopped being able to connect to the running server so it seems like the `psql` command is following the config file but the server itself isnt?

How can I debug this issue?

I have tried to use `psql -U postgres -c 'SHOW config_file'` but it just shows the config file that I have edited?

at the end of the file is:

```
include_dir = 'conf.d'          # include files ending in '.conf' from
                # a directory, e.g., 'conf.d'
```

but this conf.d folder is empty

Comment: I am trying to connect to Postgres remotely so need to get it to listen to remote traffic

Comment: What exactly is the error you get?  And what does `show listen_address;` give you in `psql`?

Answer (score 0):

There are two changes you need to make to enable PostgreSQL to accept remote connections:

- First is exactly what you've done, modify `listen_addresses` in `/etc/postgresql/<VERSION>/main/postgresql.conf` to listen on all interfaces:

  ```
  listen_addresses = '*'
  ```
- Second, you need to modify `/etc/postgresql/<VERSION>/main/pg_hba.conf` to allow remote connections. If you look at a default `pg_hba.conf` you will have a line that looks like this:

  ```
  host all all 127.0.0.1/32 md5
  ```

  That `127.0.0.1/32` is keeping PostgreSQL from accepting remote connections, so let's change it:

  ```
  host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
  ```

Restart the PostgreSQL database after making these two changes and you should be able to connect to it from a remote computer.

If you're still having issues connecting to the database remotely I'd check firewalls like iptables, etc.

Comment: I have done this exactly and I am still having an issue connecting. Any other items to check?

Comment: @MichaelRyan I'd double check host, port, username, and password to make sure If all of those lined up. You can check the postgres logs to see if they are outputting any connection errors. If they aren't outputting anything, that means your request isn't reaching the db, which hopefully will give you a place to start looking for the problem. If everything looked correct on client and db side but postgres isn't showing connection requests, then look at firewalls and things like that. Good luck!